# PostgreSQL - How many customers are active at any given month per year?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question: How many customers are active at any given month per year (e.g. ..., Jun 2005, Jul 2005,...., Jun 2006 etc)? We define active as performing at least one rental during that month.

I have made a query but I need to modify it a bit, here is my query:

```html
SELECT rental_date, to_char(rental_date, 'Mon YYYY')
FROM rental
ORDER BY rental_date desc
```

I'm trying to use "WITH" that returns the count of rentals, grouping by customer_id, to_char(rental_date, 'Mon YYYY')

[Here is the ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l68il.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The number of distinct customer_ids having records in the month:

```
SELECT to_char(rental_date, 'Mon YYYY'), COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
FROM rental
GROUP BY to_char(rental_date, 'Mon YYYY')
```

You need the DISTINCT because if one customer performed 3 rentals, the count(*) would be 3.. but you asked "how many customers are active" (answer: 1), not "how many rentals are performed"

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` `to_char(rental_date, 'YYYY-MM')` and `order by desc` by the same:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(rental_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS monthofyear, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS activecounter 
FROM rentals
GROUP BY (to_char(rental_date, 'YYYY-MM'))
ORDER BY (to_char(rental_date, 'YYYY-MM')) DESC
```

This format `YYYY-MM` can be sorted properly.